Capture a reference to a component inside a dynamically added wrapper
I want to render some components inside a wrapper, so when I have the following razor:
<Component/>

I want it to render like this:
<Wrapper>
    <Component />
</Wrapper>

I've created a custom IComponentActivator that does the job, but when I'm trying to get a reference of a component I get a InvalidCastException. For example
This works:
<ComponentIWantToBeInWrapper /> 

This doesn't
<ComponentIWantToBeInWrapper @ref=_ref /> 

As I understand reference capture tries to get an instance of the ComponentIWantToBeInWrapper type, but instead gets a Wrapper instance and then throws an error.
I wonder is there a way to make it work? Is it possible to somehow capture a child component of a wrapper instead of wrapper itself?
Minimal reproduction example:
ComponentActivator.cs
public class ComponentActivator : IComponentActivator
{
    public IComponent CreateInstance(Type componentType)
    {
        if(componentType == typeof(Component))
        {
            return (IComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DivWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(componentType))!;
        }

        if (componentType.IsGenericType && componentType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dummy<>))
        {
            var innerType = componentType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            return (IComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(innerType)!;
        }

        return (IComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(componentType)!;
    }
}

DivWrapper.razor
@typeparam T where T : ComponentBase

<div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <Dummy T="T" @attributes=Attrs />
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attrs { get; set; } = default!;
}

Dummy.cs
public class Dummy<T> : ComponentBase where T : ComponentBase
{
}

Page.razor
@page "/"

<Component />
@* <Component @ref=_ref /> this will crush an app *@


Fact - you can't create a component that resides within the render tree outside the Renderer.  You don't create instances of components, the Renderer does.  Your intent is not obvious from your question, but that's what it looks like you are trying to do.  If so, no go [unless you want to write your own version of the Blazor renderer]..

As I understand IComponentActivator creates an instances of a components and then the Renderer initializes it and renders it on a screen. In my case I want to render component inside a wrapper in some cases, but it fails if I try to capture the reference via @ref

I am tempted to answer this, but you are committing far too many Blazor sins :) [sorry if it comes across as rude]. If you can explain the UI problem you are trying to solve we can figure out a much more streamlined pattern.

No problem, feel free to point out what I'm doing wrong, because it's a new area for me. I explained my goal in the comment to the @MrCakaShaunCurtis solution: my main goal is to wrap components in a layout components based on some parameters. Something like Grid.Row Grid.Column parameters in WPF, that are available for all elements. But as you've pointed out I start to realize that there are too many problems with IComponentActivator, so I will probably think about a different solution

You need to consider what you're doing.
In your Page you will be declaring something like this:
    private MyComponent? _ref;

This is Razor and will be compiled into the component class the Razor compiler builds.
At runtime your ComponentActivator is changing the component out for MyReplacementComponent.
In your scenario MyReplacementComponent and MyComponent have no relationship.  The runtime can't cast so exception and crash.
If MyReplacementComponent inherits from MyComponent then it will work.
It interests me that this functionality is actually exposed at all.   There's all sorts of crazy out-of-bounds code you could write to really screw things up!
Are you sure you can't do what you want with more mainstream techniques?
Update base on comments
Based on your comments to the original answer, take a look at the source code for QuickGrid - QuickGrid Source.
If you want a simpler version of the code with a detailed description of what's going on then I have a repo here: Blazr.ComponentRegistration.
If what you are looking for a way to write wrapper components then take a look at this WrapperFrame in an article of mine on base components.

Thank you for an answer, my main goal is to wrap components in a layout components based on some parameters. Something like Grid.Row Grid.Column parameters in WPF, that are available for all elements. But as you've pointed out I start to realize that there are too many problems with IComponentActivator, so I will probably think about a different solution.

I know a little about components, but didn't know that functionality was publicly exposed.  I have a possible use for it, so thanks for bringing it to the surface.  See the additional information in my original answer on resources that I think will be helpful to you.   Ask another question if you get stuck in your question.
